# How do I add elements to the DOM so people can post comments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a code (down below) that has a text-box and a comment section. I also have a button where it's supposed to add that comment. I don't know the code that will post the comment below the comment section. This is my code:

```
<div id="comments">
        <fieldset><legend>Post Your Comments!</legend>
        Name: <input type="textbox" name="name"><br><br>
    </fieldset><br>
      <textarea rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Your Comments!"></textarea>
      <button>Add!</button>
```

Comment: Create an element, assign it a value, and append it as a child to your comments `div`.

Comment: Can you give an example of that? I was thinking along the lines of:
<ul value="comment"></ul>
ul.appendElement('button');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you'll want to do some kind of server-side saving of the comments, but the code below answers your question by adding the elements to the DOM.  You'll see some changes to your code, including some IDs and proper closing of input and br tags.

HTML:

```
<div id="comments">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Post Your Comments!</legend>Name:
        <input type="textbox" id="txtName" name="name" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <textarea id="txtComments" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Your Comments!"></textarea>
    <button id="btnAdd">Add!</button>
</div>
<div id="postedComments"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Create new HTML string containing name & comment
        var newComment = '<hr /><div class="name">' + $('#txtName').val() + '</div>' +
            '<div class="comment">' + $('#txtComments').val() + '</div>';
        // This creates a new jQuery object containing newComment 
        // and appends it to the posted comments section
        $(newComment).appendTo('#postedComments');
        // Clear input
        $('#txtComments').val('');
        $('#txtName').val('');
    });
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/85k8y6eo/

If you want to post the comments to the server and only add them to the DOM after they have been saved on the server, look into jQuery's post() (or other similar AJAX functions).  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines (in pure JavaScript):

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var addButton = document.getElementById("add");
  addButton.addEventListener("click", addComment);

  var theDiv = document.getElementById("comments");

  function addComment() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var comments = document.getElementById("post").value;
    var newPara = document.createElement("P");
    newPara.innerHTML = "<u>" + name + "</u><br/>" + comments;

    theDiv.appendChild(newPara);

  }

};
```

```html
<div id="comments">
  <h3>Post Your Comments!</h3>
  Name:
  <input type="textbox" name="name" id="name">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <textarea id="post" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Your Comments!"></textarea>
  <br/>
  <button id="add">Add!</button>
</div>
```